# onClick not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to learn android development with Android Studio but I can't seem to figure out why my clicks are not registering. Is there something I'm missing here?

I don't like the way Stack Overflow FORCES me to format things they way THEY want. Here is pastebin! :_

http://pastebin.com/hdzZpsud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you didn't set the listener. So you should add `changeText()` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);`.

Comment: Your comment was first. Thank you very much also.

Comment: I just did. I would have upvoted both of you as well but I don't have the rep to do so..

Answer (score 5):

call this `changeText()`  method inside `onCreate()` method of your activity

your activity should look like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        changeText();
    }

    public void changeText(){

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.largetext);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                button.setText("Button has been pressed");
                text.setText("The large text has been changed");
            }
        });

    }
}
```